# How to clip polygon such that only regions in 'line of sight' from a point remain

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, intersect

I am using ArcGIS.

My point represents a monitoring station and is located within a polygon representing a river catchment.

I have created a buffer of 300m representing the detection range of the monitoring station and I have clipped this to the polygon area using the intersection tool.

I want to further clip the buffer region so that it only contains the polygon area in 'line of sight' from the monitoring station.

The image shows the GIS output I have so far achieved, with the clipped buffer region in purple, but with areas marked in red that are not in line of sight of the monitoring station and should therefore be removed. Is there a tool to achieve this, perhaps with radiating lines from the monitoring station?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify what GIS software you are using (and the license level, if using ArcGIS). "Is it possible?" questions nearly always have the answer, "Yes," so you probably want to focus on "How is it possible?" Have you tried using an overlay function like Union then selecting out the features you want to keep?

Comment: I am not sure how Union would calculate which regions of the polygon are in line of sight of the point

Comment: Your title asks how to clip a polygon with a polygon. Are you really asking how to generate a visibilty polygon? That's a very different question. In addition to license level, you'd need to mention which extensions you have available (if 3D Analyst isn't available, it's much more difficult, and if neither 3D nor Spatial Analyst is available, you have an unpleasant bit of coding ahead)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to 3D analyst or Spatial Analyst, but I think a visibility polygon would be the right way forward. I will see what QGIS has to offer.

Comment: The tool is called Viewshed.  But yes, it is only available with advanced licensing.
 http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/viewshed.htm